# Python: How to read multiple Excel sheets into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From Excel, how can I parse 'Sheet1' and 'Sheet2' in to a `list`? I'm currently using `xlrd`, as shown in the code below.

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import xlrd
import sys

loc = 'excel.xlsx'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc, encoding_override="iso-8859-5, cyrillic")
wb_name = wb.sheet_names()
count = len(wb_name)
data = []
column_excel =('Name', 'Course', 'Cost', 'level')
count_column = len(column_excel)
for i in range(count):
    ow = xlrd.open_workbook('excel.xlsx').sheet_by_index(i)
    for x in range (0, 100):
        for i in range(2):
            try:
                if ow.cell_value(0, x) == column_excel[i]:
                    ips = ow.col_values(x, 1)
                    data.append(ips)
                    break
            except IndexError:
                continue
print(data)
```

My results:

```
[['Andre'], [1], [200], [5],
['Sam'], [2], [100], [8],
[7], ['Antony'], [4], [150],
[9], ['Ben'], [3], [500]]
```

Expected output:

```
[['Andre'], [1], [200], [5],
['Sam'], [2], [100], [8],
['Antony'], [4], [7], [150],
['Ben'], [3], [9], [500]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to use `pandas` to read the XLSX file, rather than `xlrd`, things become much simpler, from a coding perspective. Additionally, as the `.append()` function is quite clever in its design, the columns are auto-aligned (providing the column name is the same) - which can be helpful since the sheets have different column order.

[The official pandas `read_excel` docs can be found here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Sample code:
When calling the `.read_excel()` using multiple sheets, a `dict` of DataFrames (`df_`) is returned.  The second line of code is used to combine the DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd

df_ = pd.read_excel('courses.xlsx', sheet_name=['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'])
df = pd.DataFrame().append([df_[i] for i in df_]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output (as a DataFrame):

```
      Name  Course  Cost  level
0    Andre       1   200      5
1      Sam       2   100      8
2  Anthony       4   150      7
3      Ben       3   500      9
```

Output (as a list):

```
>>> df.to_numpy().tolist()

[['Andre', 1, 200, 5],
 ['Sam', 2, 100, 8],
 ['Anthony', 4, 150, 7],
 ['Ben', 3, 500, 9]]
```

Acknowledgement:
This list output is not identical (in format) to the expected output in the question. I presume this is a design flaw, as a the output of this answer provides a list of *records* rather than a list of individual fields - which may later become difficult to manage.

Comment: Additional information: If you are using multiple excel files, you can read them in in a loop and append the resulting dataframe to a list. This list you can later unite into a big dataframe with `big_df = pd.concat(list_variable)`

Comment: @Dustin - Yes, absolutely correct, thank you for the additional information.